# #define PI_THREAD(X) void *X (void *dummy)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, macros

This PI_THREAD(X) is defined as void*X(void * dummy) which a function with its own name.  return void* and void* as parameter.  I don't see how it's related to a thread.

The usage of this macro,

```
  /*
 * softPwmThread:
 *  Thread to do the actual PWM output
 *********************************************************************************
 */

static PI_THREAD (softPwmThread)
{
  int pin, mark, space ;

  pin    = newPin ;
  newPin = -1 ;

  piHiPri (50) ;

  for (;;)
  {
    mark  = marks [pin] ;
    space = range [pin] - mark ;

    if (mark != 0)
      digitalWrite (pin, HIGH) ;
    delayMicroseconds (mark * 100) ;

    if (space != 0)
      digitalWrite (pin, LOW) ;
    delayMicroseconds (space * 100) ;
  }

  return NULL ;
}
```

In Linux, a thread is related to pthread object right?  how this void*X(void* dummy) relate to thread?

Answer (score 1):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
               void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

You can see that the `start_routine` of a thread has a prototype of taking a parameter of `void *`, and return a `void *`.

In your example, the function doesn't need a parameter to work, and doesn't need to return anything meaningful. But it still must have a prototype like this to be used to create new thread. So the macro:

```
#define PI_THREAD(X) void *X (void *dummy)
```

`dummy` is the parameter that is useless, and you need to `return NULL` in the function to comply with the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The pthreads API creates threads that run user-specified functions.  The [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function assumes that this function has the signature

```
void* function(void* arg);
```

Therefore, it makes sense for the macro to define functions that take in a `void*` and return a `void*`, since that's the signature of a function that would be called and run as a thread routine.

Hope this helps!